# What is the notation for the number of elements in a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let's say S = {1, 2, 3}.
There are 3 elements in S. How do I express this in notation?
I tried using google but I could not find what I was looking for.

Comment: Typically the notation is $|S|$ for the cardinality of (number of elements in) $S$.

Comment: I will be using that then. Thank you.

Comment: @Tad See my answer below for alternative notational conventions. I have also edited your question with the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the cardinality of the set. There are many addition rules, etc. associated with it, but I will not say anything about that here. You can easily search that up on Google. The notation used for the cardinality of a set $S$ is usually one of the following:
$$\mathrm{card}(S), \# S, |S|, \overline{\overline{S}}$$
Usually, though, $|S|$ is used (I prefer $\mathrm{card}(S)$, as $|S|$ could, at least in category theory, be mistaken for the geometric realization functor).

Comment: I'm reading the wiki page on cardinality. Very fancy notations on this page.

Comment: @Tad Yes, Wikipedia lists all notations that the editors of that page might have seen before; I listed the first three out of memory, and then saw Wikipedia for the last one. I hope this answer helped,

Comment: Yes it did. It's always better to know the technical notations instead making them up!

Comment: @Tad Yeah, that's true. Do tell me if I can be of any more assistance.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar The last one doesn't appear familiar to me at all... I wonder who uses this...

Comment: @AlexR I do not know; I only remember actually ever seeing the first three. As I said in a comment above, ``I listed the first three out of memory, and then saw Wikipedia for the last one.''

Comment: The notation $\overline{\overline S}$ is the oldest one, introduced by Cantor.

Comment: @bof Thanks for enlightening me :) Has been superceeded by now I guess...

Comment: @bof Of course! I now remember reading it in his paper titled ``On the foundations of transfinite numbers'' or s/t like that.

Answer (score 0):

As SDevalapurkar said they are a lot of notations for cardinality of a set but I prefer the use of $|S|$ because it is conceptually close (if not the same) to the concept of absolute value that is the [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) of dimension 1.